# Erro ao calcular altura de árvore Trie em C

Tags: c, recursão

Estou precisando implementar um código que calcule a altura de uma arvore *Trie* na linguagem C.

A `struct` do *nó* é a seguinte:

```c
struct trie_cel {
    char tipo; // 'I': interno / 'P': palavra
    struct trie_cel *filho[TAMANHO_ALFABETO]; // Utilizar a funcao CHAR_TO_INDEX para obter o no filho de cada letra.
};
typedef struct trie_cel no;
```

Estou tentando calcular a altura de uma árvore *Trie* com recursão, esta é minha função:

```c
int altura(no* r) {
    if(r == NULL) return -1;
    if(!r) return 0;
    int alt = 0;
    int alturaM = 0;
    no** i = r->filho;
    no** fim = i + (sizeof(r->filho) / sizeof(no *));
    while(i != fim){
        alt = altura(r->filho[i])+1;
        if(alt > alturaM){
            alturaM = alt;
        }
    }
    return alturaM;
}
```

Porém está sendo apresentado o seguinte erro e não estou conseguindo localiza-lo.

```
trie.cpp: In function ‘int altura(no*)’:
trie.cpp:146:32: error: invalid types ‘trie_cel* [27][no** {aka trie_cel**}]’ for array subscript
         alt = altura(r->filho[i])+1;
                                ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você tá tentando usar o tipo `no**` como índice do *array*, o que não é possível.

Você tem que mudar estas linhas

```c
no** i = r->filho;
no** fim = i + (sizeof(r->filho) / sizeof(no *));
```

Para

```c
int i = 0;
int fim = TAMANHO_ALFABETO;
```

E adicionar `1` à variável `i` a cada repetição do *loop* no fim do `while`

Ou você pode transformar isso em um `for` *loop*

```c
int altura(no *r) {
    if(r == NULL) return -1;
    if(!r) return 0;
    int alt = 0;
    int alturaM = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO_ALFABETO; i++) {
        alt = altura(r->filho[i])+1;
        if(alt > alturaM){
            alturaM = alt;
        }
    }
    return alturaM;
}
```